# Bind Multiple Value to Bar Chart Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, bar-chart

I have been trying to have a chart with horizontal bars, with multiple values in `x-axis`.

In my chart, `y-axis` will be "Serial Number", however, I have 2 values in `x-axis`.

i) Status
 ii) Total Time: calculated based on (EndTime - StartTime).

How could I go about that?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify what language and user interface toolkit you are wanting to use for this. Also a minimal code sample of your attempt would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, I m using c# asp.net